# How to add Maven dependencies in Eclipse libaries

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Can any one explain how to add Maven dependency JAR i.e. build path libraries? To be very specific how to include JAR file mentioned in pom.xml to Java build path? Maven dependencies - unable to see jars over here.

Don't have a option to update Maven dependencies. Also executed the script `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, seen on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not have any need to deal with such a task manually. Here is the correct procedure for importing of maven project to your Eclipse IDE:

1. Make sure you have m2eclipse plugin installed (Maven support for Eclipse). As far I remember it is included to Eclipse IDE for JEE developers by default.
2. Checkout your maven project to any directory
3. From this directory (root pom.xml is located in), run: **mvn eclipse:eclipse**
4. Go to Eclipse, File -> Import, select "Existing maven project"
5. Select directory where your root pom.xml is located, Eclipse should find all maven modules.
6. Optional: if eclipse will tell you that it can't recognize some maven plugins - ignore this, just continue.

If you follow this instruction, IDE will create all maven modules as eclipse projects and you will have an option to update maven dependencies and also willsee all of them rigth in IDE.